# Maximise a function over one parameter that is continuous, and one that is discrete

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have a function that I would like to maximise with respect to two parameters: one continuous, another which is discrete.

A simple example of this might be the following:

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {1000}];
z[c_, d_Integer] := Sum[data[[i]]^c, {i, 1, d}];
```

I would like to maximise this function $z$ over choice of $c$ - a continuous variable; and $d$ - a discrete one.

At the moment, I have been iteratively searching for a solution over $c$, then using this value for $c$, in order to maximise (using the Mathematica function $Maximize$ with the domain type specified as $Integers$) the function over $d$. I then repeat the continuous maximisation using the value of $d$ found, continuing *ad infinitum*.

Does anyone know of a solution that will *simultaneously* search for a maximum over both variables?

Note that this is a merely supposed to be an indicative example, *not* the actual function, so please do not suggest 'tricks' that are only relevant to this particular function form.

Best,

Ben

Comment: Consider the function `z[c, Round[d]]`…

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have tried the edits shown in the new question - it seems to sort of work. I get a warning/error. Any ideas?

Comment: Wasn't the warning self-explanatory? Somehow, you have an idea of a "reasonable region", no?

Comment: Ok, I will close the question. I suspect the example I have given isn't quite perfect! Thanks for your help. Best, Ben

Comment: You can use `NMaximize` and add in the constraints that `Element[d,Integers]`. Possibly `Maximize` will also handle that constraint; depends on the specifics of the objective function and other constraints if any.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Trying it I either get that the function seems to not evaluate because it starts with values outside of integers for d. To be clear I am using $NMaximize[z[c, d], \{Element[d, Integers], Element[c, Reals]\}]$. Any ideas?

Comment: Syntax might be an issue. And the specifics of the problem. For this example one can do: `data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {1000}];
z[c_, d_Integer] := Sum[Abs[data[[i]]^c], {i, 1, d}];NMinimize[{z[c, d], Element[d, Integers], 1000 >= d >= 1, c >= 0}, {c,
   d}]` and get a viable result.

Answer (score 1):

The following workaround suggested by user *Guess who it is* works ok:

```
NMaximize[{z[c, Round[d]],d>0},{c,d},Reals]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `z[c, d]` is independent of `c`

```
RandomSeed[1];

data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {1000}];
z[c_, d_Integer] := Sum[data[[i]]^d, {i, 1, d}];

MaximalBy[{#, z[c, #]} & /@ Range[2, 1000], Last]
```

> {{1000, 1.455004716249383*10^489}}

Since the data contains negative values, even powers are highly likely to give the largest values.

```
MaximalBy[{#, z[c, #]} & /@ Range[2, 1000, 2], Last]
```

> {{1000, 1.455004716249383*10^489}}

Comment: Hi, my apologies for the error in the function; it should have been to the power $c$. Not sure whether the above answer still applies, but many thanks nonetheless. Best, Ben